# Помогите составить sql запрос, выводящий парные элементы из одной таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql

Итак,задача,приведенная к сферическому виду в вакууме -
Дано:

```
TABLE mytable 
  INT id (primary_key)
  TEXT target ('id1,id2,id3 ... ')//id других полей из этой же таблицы, через запятую
  BOOL condition (true/false)//на самом деле условие гораздо сложнее
```

Один элемент может быть парным сразу к нескольким. Но в базу они попадают строго попарно.

Задача:
Получить в результате mysql-запроса только парные поля (такие, что id первой есть в targets второй,id второй есть в targets первой и condition у них обоих true)

UP:
[Решение для выборки всех полей по такому условию](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e148/24). Как мне теперь приделать к нему limit так, чтобы по прежнему получать только парные элементы? Если просто в лоб приписать туда лимит, то пары к некоторым полям попадают под него,и поле остается без пары. Я пробовал с помощью UNION получать поля сразу попарно, но у меня из этого ничего не вышло, т.к. я не смог связать запросы между собой.

*P.S. в моих реальных условиях limit на входе от 8 и больше,кратный четырем,но интересно было бы увидеть общее решение. 3 элемента тоже могут быть попарно между друг другом связаны.*

Comment: Вы в одном из ответов к вопросу про CSS негодовали что у автора вопроса не возникло мысли про то что можно было бы открыть htmlbooks. Но при этом сами поленились открыть книгу по SQL и MySQL!!! Пишите Ваши попытки и что конкретно не получилось, что именно у ВАс не получается?

Comment: Негодовать то я негодовал,но к своему негодованию я прикрепил ссылку на то, что автор мог бы найти и сам. Вы же, в отличие от меня, по всей видимости способны только на негодование.

Comment: Что бы вы там ни говорили, структура ужасна. Читайте про нормализацию БД. Такие велосипеды ни к чему хорошему не приводят. Разве что ваша цель создать нечто очень медленное либо работающее на очень малых объемах данных, но тогда можно использовать и обычные файлы вместо БД. Здесь, например, неплохо неплохо описана тема нормализации: http://habrahabr.ru/post/193756/

Answer (score 1):

Неверная организация рекурсивного списка. Прочитайте принципы нормализации баз данных и принципы построения БД. И решение к вам придет само.

P.S.: если все же само не придет, то http://habrahabr.ru/post/43955/

Comment: У меня нет никакой иерархии, у меня пары. Просто один элемент может быть парным сразу к нескольким. Но в базу они попадают строго попарно.

Comment: ну попробуйте так
SELECT * FROM mytable m, mytable m2
where m2.text like to_char(m.id) and m.text like to_char(m2.id) and m.condition = true and m2.condition = true

Эх.. горазды же тут все спорить. Говорят вам неверное построение рекурсивного списка. Ваше поле TEXT показывает отношение - что означает что данная запись является подчиненной другой, в т.ч. и нескольким может. Это и есть иерархический список.. попробуйте на листочке наприсовать вашу подчиненность. Увидите.

Comment: Запрос типа  SELECT * FROM mytable m, mytable m2 у меня выдает ошибку,я уже пробовал так сделать

Comment: Что за ошибка ?

Comment: Не может в таком запросе быть какой-либо ошибки. Максимум если поля в SELECT не определены. Вот и определите их к примеру SElect m.id, m1.id или же SELECT m.*,m1.*. если ошибка при дальшейней обработке значит надо имена одинаковых полей из разных таблиц ассоциировать по разному.

Comment: [Довел ваш запрос до ума](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/861c3/3). А вместо join (склеивания парных полей в одно) никак нельзя в результате получать парные поля по отдельности? В принципе, это решение я уже могу использовать,но придется расклеивать теперь эти поля с помощью php.. А с помощью php изначально можно было не задавать этот вопрос. Всегда можно выгрузить хоть всю таблицу и сделать с ней что хочешь